# Runtime error 9: Subscript out of range - Pulling data from another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro that pulls data from one workbook and places it into another. I think I have the code pretty much right except for an error I'm getting in one of my loops:

"Runtime error 9: Subscript out of range"

Here is the code:

```
Sub PullFromRunsheetsTest2()



Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Dim file As Variant, a As String, columnItertor As Integer, path As String
     path = "C:\Users\msala\Desktop\Runsheets\"

   file = Dir(path & "Runsheet*")
   Do Until file = ""  ''looking at the first file and loops until the last one
        columnIterator = 0  ''setting this as the first set of 8 numbers - will shift the next set of numbers down 8 so they don't overwrite themselves
        rowIterator = 0
              Do Until rowIterator = 7

                     a = Workbooks(file).Worksheets("Pacman Runsheet").Cells(7, (2 + rowIterator)).Value '' Set "a" = whatever value is in B7, and iterate through that row 
                     ''^^^^(THIS IS WHERE I'M GETTING THE ERROR)


                     ActiveSheet.Cells(5 + rowIterator + columnIterator * 8, 1).Value = a ''take that value and put it in this column, iterate through.

              rowIterator = rowIterator + 1
              Loop

        columnIterator = columnIterator + 1 ''(ignore this for now)

        file = Dir()
  Loop



End Sub
```

From what I've read it seems like there's some sort of problem with maybe the data type of `a`? Not entirely sure what that might be though. Am I accidentally declaring `a` as an `array` somewhere?

Comment: In `Cells` commands, rows come first, columns second - it looks like (since you have added `rowIterator` to the second element), that you have these swapped around the wrong way?

Comment: And `Subscript out of range` generally means you've tried to access an element that doesn't exist inside an array

Comment: @Dave The reason I use rowIterator for the columns of the second Cells command is because I basically want to move down that column at the same rate that I move across the row in the other sheet. I could see how that would be confusing though.

Comment: @Dave Also, what do you mean "tried to access an element that doesn't exist inside an array"?

Comment: All those dots in one line are hard to debug. `Workbooks(file)` could be the error or `Worksheets("Pacman Runsheet")` or `Cells(...` One possibility is to declare workbook variables and worksheet variables, set them on different lines, and see which line has the error. Get it down to one dot operator per line. In this case, I suspect that @Dave is right and the `Cells()` call is the problem.

Comment: How might I get it down to 1 dot operator per line? @JohnColeman

Comment: If `wb` is a workbook variable and `ws` is a worksheet variable, then `Set wb = Workbooks(file)` in one line, `Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Pacman Runsheet")` in the next, and then, finally, `a = ws.Cells(....` in the last. One of those three lines will fail. Which one should make the problem apparent.